# Recursion questions

Tags: induction, recursion

Let $M$ be a set, $e\in M$, and $F:M\rightarrow M$.  Define $r$ on $\mathbb{N}$ by $r(0)=e$, and, for all $k$, $k\in \mathbb{N}$, $r(s(k))=F(r(k))$.

Assume that $F$ maps $M$ $1\text{-}1$ and onto $M$.  Define a function $F$ for which $r$ does not map onto $M$.  Also, define a function $F$ for which $r$ is not $1\text{-}1$ on $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: ...please....?? And what have **you** done so far?

Comment: Please [take a look at how I've edited your MathJax code](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1bb47435-e15c-481e-b95d-1a8dcab1181a/view-source); I encourage you to emulate it. In particular, each "stretch" of mathematics should be in one piece of MathJax. For example, instead of writing something like `$a$ $\otimes$ $b$`, you should write `$a\otimes b$`. You can find some good starting points on how to format mathematics on the site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020). [This AMS reference](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) is very useful.

Comment: @DonAntonio: If you're going to insist on putting "1-1" in MathJax, you need to ensure somehow that the hyphen will not (as it will otherwise be automatically) considered a minus sign.

Comment: @Zev Chonoles: Thanks.  That's helpful.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: You didn’t say, but I’m assuming that $Nat$ is $\Bbb N$, the set of natural numbers (including $0$), and that $s$ is the successor function. If $M=\{e\}$, $r$ will always map $\Bbb N$ onto $M$, so we must assume that $M$ contains at least one other element.

- If $F:M\to M$ is the identity function, what does $r$ turn out to be?

Comment: In this case, $r$ is the constant function which always returns $e$.  Adding an extra element to M, as you suggest, implies $r$ isn't onto $M$.

Comment: @TLP: (I think that you were probably expected to assume that $M$ contained at least two elements.) That’s right; and that means that $r$ meets both of the requirements, since it’s clearly not $1$-$1$, either.

Comment: As an example of an $F$ for which r is not 1-1 on $\mathbb{N}$, let  $F$ be the identity function and let $r(0)=1$ and, for all $k$, $k\in \mathbb{N}$, $r(s(k))=F(r(k))$.  Then r is a constant function on $\mathbb{N}$, always returning 1.

Comment: @TLP: Whoa! You can’t set $r(0)=1$: it’s all part of the same question, so you already know that $r(0)=e\in M$. The point of my last comment is that you don’t need to do anything else: taking $F$ to be the identity map on $M$ automatically gives you the constant function $r(n)=e$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$, which is certainly not $1$-$1$.

Comment: I now see what my mistake was.  I was understanding ''$r$ is not 1-1 on $\mathbb{N}$'' to ask us to an $$r:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}.$$  That doesn't make sense, though, with the setup.

Comment: @TLP: Sorry; I had realized that that was probably the source of the confusion, but I forgot to comment. Yes, the *on* $\Bbb N$ here just means that the domain is $\Bbb N$, not that it’s a function from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N$.